# How to move the chapter title upwards on page?

Tags: spacing, formatting, chapters

How can I get the chapter higher on the page in order to get as many words as possible per page. 
Here is my MWE of what I am talking about.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\chapter{example}
How do I get chapter to go higher on the page. In order to get as many words per page. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also would like to have chapter number and chapter title in one line.

Comment: Your title and body is contradicting... regardless, why do you use a `\chapter` then? Why not use something like a `\section`?

Comment: I added a figure of your MWE, but also put on a `showframe` to show the text margins.

Comment: I would use section but I was asked to keep everything in chapter form. Is there a way that I can get it to say Chapter 1 for example at the top of the page instead of the middle? If you could please help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

The vertical skip between text page top margin and the chapter title is controlled by `\vspace*{50\p@}` in `\@makechapterhead`. (`\p@` is an internal representation for `pt`)

Either redefine this command completely or use a `\xpatchcmd` replacing `\vspace*{50\p@}` with some other length, that's easier to change, in a special length register, say `\chaptertopskip`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newlength{\chaptertopskip}
\setlength{\chaptertopskip}{10pt}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{\chaptertopskip}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure!!!}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{example}
How do I get chapter to go higher on the page. In order to get as many words per page. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Changing the wrap and bottom skip as well:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newlength{\chaptertopskip}
\newlength{\chapterbottomskip}
\setlength{\chaptertopskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\chapterbottomskip}{10pt}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{\chaptertopskip}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter\ 
%        \par\nobreak
%        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip \chapterbottomskip
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{example}
How do I get chapter to go higher on the page. In order to get as many words per page. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the placement of where it says chapter. But is there a way to just make it say the chapter number and the chapter title on the same line?

Comment: @rabin: That's another question -- you asked for the movement of the chapter header.

Comment: @rabin: See the update at the bottom

Comment: Thank You very much. You have no idea how much I appreciate it.

Comment: @rabin: If it's what you requested, please consider to accept it later on

Comment: Funny thing, last week i redefined the chapterhead for the MDT thing in almost the same way :-)

Answer (score 5):

The default `\chapter` command issues three different spaces to set the chapter heading:

1. Space from the top of the text block to the word **Chapter**; default is 50pt.
2. Space between **Chapter** and the chapter title; default is 20pt.
3. Space between the chapter title and the chapter body text; default is 40pt.

All of this is made by the macro `\@makechapterhead` (from [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co); emphasis added):

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}% <------------------------------------ (1)
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@% <--------------------------------- (2)
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@% <------------------------------------- (3)
  }}
```

For unnumbered chapters, there are still two spaces (1) and (3) above given as part of `\@makeschapterhead`:

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}% <------------------------------------ (1)
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@% <------------------------------------- (3)
  }}
```

You can either get rid of these using an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch, but it may be better to just write your own `\@makechapterhead` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  {\noindent\raggedright\normalfont% Alignment and font reset
   \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space\thechapter~~#1\par\nobreak}% Formatting
  \vspace{\baselineskip}% ...just a little space
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe}% Just to show the frame

\begin{document}

\chapter{Example}
How do I get chapter to go higher on the page. In order to get as many words per page. 

\end{document}
```

You can do something similar for `\@makeschapterhead`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need it for a certain chapter just once, you might use a very dirty workaround (that might put you into Latex jail). You can use `\chapter{\vspace*{-2em} Chapter 1}` lifting it by approximately two lines.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  `-2\baselineskip` is a bit more direct.  `em` is usually considered a horizontal dimension, and `ex` the corresponding vertical dimension.

Comment: Beware: this is going to mess up the index! I have not yet found a solution to change a single chapter...