# How to move the words "Nomenclature and Bibliography" at the top of the page?

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, header-footer, fontsize, nomenclature

I have two issues. First, I have to move the words "Nomenclature" and "Bibliography" at the top of the page. Right now these words appear 5 cm from the page border. I am using the following script

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{cases}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Subscripts}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{C}{Superscripts}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{D}{Acronyms{}}}}}%
]}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\Large Nomenclature}
\printnomenclature[0.75in]
```

The font size of the Nomenclature is fine but not the position

Second, I have the same problem for the word Bibliography. It is not located at the top of the page and in this case it has a bigger font than Nomenclature. Actuaally Nomenclature has font Large as all the other headings.

In this case I am using:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
..
..
\end{thebibliography}
```

Here below the output in pdf enter image description here
[image]

Comment: Bibilography is written using \chapter*{\bibname}, so see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309920/how-to-move-the-chapter-title-upwards-on-page

Comment: Unfortunately I developed the bibliography with {thebibliography} it is the easiest way to make the bibliography. So Is there a way to use the same method, {thebibliography} and reducing the fonts of the bibliography and move it up in the page?

Comment: One alternative is to modify thebilibography to not call \chapter*, but the replacing \@makehapterhead is easier.  (I suspect nomenclature uses \section*)

Comment: Hi, I call the bibliography in this way: \begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibliographystyle{tag} 

\bibitem{Amst} Armstrong, 
\end{thebibliography} and I am using \usepackage{nomencl} for the nnomenclature and I am using the \section{Introduction} It does not work the \@makehapterhead  it says You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.

Comment: Oops, for \chapter* you need to modify \@makeschapterhead, not \@makechapterhead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a bib file available, so I called `\chapter*{\bibname}` directly.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\bgroup% make changes termporary
\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{25\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    %\Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    %\vskip 40\p@
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\chapter*{\bibname}
After...
\egroup
\end{document}
```