# Latex how to put appendix title more up

Tags: titles, report, appendix, layout

I'm using the latex class report.

As I do not want to have heavy style for the chapters like Lenny Sonny. I use the following:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter. }{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

So I am quite happy when I create a chapter. However, for the chapter of the appendix I do not want to have such a huge space between the title and the top of the page [see image]. Hence, my question is: for each title of chapters in the appendix, how to put the title [title of appendix only) more up?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I borrowed my response from a discussion in another Stack Exchange thread and modified it based on how I understand your question. Maybe looking at this can also be helpful: [How to move the chapter title upwards on page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309920/how-to-move-the-chapter-title-upwards-on-page)

But here is an MWE based on the information you provided. I hope it is what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter. }{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\Blindtext

\appendix

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
    {\noindent\raggedright\normalfont% Alignment and font reset
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space\thechapter~~#1\par\nobreak}% Formatting
    \vspace{\baselineskip}% ...just a little space
}
\makeatother

\chapter{Move Up}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Jennifer, thanks so much it is what I look for.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!