# How can I move the title of one chapter upwards on the page?

Tags: spacing, chapters, titles

I have this code:

```
    \documentclass[oneside]{book}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Example 1}
    
    Text chapter 1
    
    \chapter{Example 2}
    
    Text chapter 2
    
    \end{document}
```

Which gives me these two pages:

[image]

[image]

My question is: how can I move, for example, the title of chapter 2 upwards on the page while leaving the title of chapter 1 in the same place?

PS: My question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309920/how-to-move-the-chapter-title-upwards-on-page) but I would like to move the title of only one chapter upwards.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you type your question so that it is self-contained.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier if you use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`).

```
% upchapterprob.tex  SE 615713

%   \documentclass[oneside]{book}
   \documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

    \begin{document}
    \setlength{\textheight}{0.4\textheight} %% just for printing convenience   
    
    \chapter{Example 1}
    
    Text chapter 1

    \addtolength{\beforechapskip}{-0.5in} % reduce space above title
    \chapter{Example 2}
    \addtolength{\beforechapskip}{0.5in} % restore space above title

    Text chapter 2

    \chapter{Example 3}

    Text chapter 3
    
    \end{document}

%%%% if using the book class instead of memoir then put the following,
%%%% less any typos, in the preamble. It is a redefinition of some book 
%%%% class code.

\newlength{\beforechapskip}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{50pt}
\makeatletter
%% revised \@makechapterhead
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{\beforechapskip}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne
     \if@mainmatter
       \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
       \par\nobreak
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
   \fi
   \interlinepenalty\@M
   \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
   \vskip 40\p@
 }}
\makeatother
```

First page:

[image]

Second page:

[image]

Third page:

[image]